# Display child form on form load with parent form behind

Tags: c#, winforms

I want in display child form on application load with parent form disable behind child form. How can i achive this in windows application c#?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show form2 from form1 you can follow this method also

```
 f2 = new Form2();
 f2.ShowDialog(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    f2 = new Form2();
    f2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide or show forms using form1.Show() or form1.Hide().
But before hiding i will tell you to Preserve the instance of Form1 
and use it to Show or Hide

```
Form2 parent= new Form2();        
parent.Hide();

Form1 child= new Form1();        
child.Show();
```

or You can minimize parent Form and show child
using this

```
Form2 parent= new Form2();        

Form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```